# How to create an Angular model that links to another model?

Tags: angular, model, ruby-on-rails-5, angular7

I'm using Angular 7 and Rails 5.  I have this model, src/app/order.ts,

```
import { Product } from './product';

export class Order{
    public id:number;
    public reference:string;
    public product:Product;

}
```

and then I add an order using the below service call ...

src/app/order-add/order-add.component.html

```
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-xs-4 control-label" for="orderProduct">Product: </label>
        <div class="col-xs-8">
              <select [(ngModel)]="order.product" name="orderProduct">
                <option *ngFor="let product of products; let i = index" [value]="products[i].id" [selected]="order !== 'undefined' && products[i].id == order.product?.id">
                  {{product.name}}
                </option>
              </select>
        </div>

        <label class="col-xs-4 control-label" for="orderReference">Order Reference: </label>
        <div class="col-xs-8">
            <input type="text" style="width: 300px" class="form-control" required
                [(ngModel)]="order.reference" name="orderReference">
        </div>
        <div>
                <input type="submit" [value]="order.id !== undefined ? 'Update' : 'Create'" />
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Here's the HTML used to add the order ...

```
src/app/order-add/order-add.component.ts

    ...
  public onSubmit(){
    console.log("Adding an order: " + this.order.reference);
    if(this.order.id){
      this.apiService.update("orders/"+this.order.id,this.order).subscribe((r)=>{
        console.log(r);
        alert("Order updated !");
      })
    }
    else
      this.apiService.post("orders",this.order).subscribe((r)=>{
      console.log(r);
      this.order = new Order();
      alert("Order added !");
    });
  }

}
```

I set up a Rails 5 controller to do the adding, which looks like below ...

```
class OrdersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_order, only: [:show, :update, :destroy]

    ...

  # POST /orders
  def create
    @order = Order.new(order_params)

    if @order.save
      render json: @order, status: :created, location: @order
    else
      render json: @order.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end
    ...

    # Only allow a trusted parameter "white list" through.
    def order_params
      params.require(:order).permit(:reference,:product_id)
    end
```

but the product submitted never gets added, despite the fact I select it in my drop down.  Here's the Rails controller log (notice no product) ...

```
Started POST "/orders" for ::1 at 2019-09-01 12:01:31 -0500
Processing by OrdersController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"product"=>"3", "reference"=>"22xxx", "order"=>{"reference"=>"22xxx"}}
   (0.3ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (1.3ms)  INSERT INTO "orders" ("reference", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3) RETURNING "id"  [["reference", "22xxx"], ["created_at", "2019-09-01 17:01:31.975467"], ["updated_at", "2019-09-01 17:01:31.975467"]]
   (0.4ms)  COMMIT
Completed 201 Created in 16ms (Views: 0.9ms | ActiveRecord: 23.5ms)
```

Do I need to do something else in my Angular model or Rails controller to make sure the product is submitted?

Comment: <option *ngFor="let product of products; let i = index" [value]="products[i].id" [selected]="order !== 'undefined' && products[i].id == order.product?.id">

In this line why did you use products[i].id since you can reference the same product using the product variable from *ngFor loop?

Comment: order !== 'undefined'  seems odd, because most probably you meant order !== undefined (I prefer order != null)

Comment: Is `<select [(ngModel)]="order.product" name="orderProduct">` going to be converted to `product_id` as required by `order_params`?

Answer (score 0):

https://angular.io/api/forms/NgSelectOption

you need to change the value-Sector

```
<option *ngFor="let product of products; let i = index" [ngValue]="product" [selected]="order !== 'undefined' && products[i].id == order.product?.id">
              {{product.name}}
 </option>
```

because [value] just tracks the string value and not the object.

Comment: Gave taht a whirl but although I see the parameters coming in on teh Rails log, (e.g. 'Parameters: {"product"=>{"id"=>4, "name"=>"Product 004", "created_at"=>"2019-08-16T20:26:47.148Z", "updated_at"=>"2019-08-16T20:26:47.148Z"}, "reference"=>"xxxa2", "order"=>{"reference"=>"xxxa2"}}'), the product isn't added to the database, (sql = ' INSERT INTO "orders" ("reference", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3) RETURNING "id"  [["reference", "xxxa2"], ["created_at", "2019-09-04 14:45:50.246580"], ["updated_at", "2019-09-04 14:45:50.246580"]]')

Answer (score 0):

You can try using change event with a select tag

```
 <select [(ngModel)]="selectedProductIndex" name="orderProduct" (change)="onProductChange(selectedProductId)">
                    <option *ngFor="let product of products; let i = index" [value]="i" [selected]="order !== 'undefined' && products[i].id == order.product?.id">
                      {{product.name}}
                    </option>
                  </select>
```

ts code:-

```
  selectedProductIndex: number; 
  onProductChange(selectedProductIndex: number) { 
    this.order.product = products[selectedProductIndex];
  }
```